# How to know add/edit page in hook_form_alter?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to know whether form is add/edit in hook_form_alter. In Drupal 7 we can get all these in hook_form_alter.

I tried like this in D7:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check pages(s) , don't use $_GET.
    if (strpos($form['#action'], '/add/') !== FALSE) {
      $page = 'add';
    }
    if (strpos($form['#action'], '/edit') !== FALSE) {
      $page = 'edit';
    }
}
```

Here I am getting add/edit in D7. Whereas in D8 I am not getting any it in $form['#actions']. And i don't want to use $_GET.
Is there any way to check add/edit page in hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In D8 you can get the operation of an entity form with the form object:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation() == 'edit') {
    $page = 'edit';
  }
}
```

Comment: This Code is working fine, except for taxonomy edit page.
Will figure out that..
Thanks for your answer

Comment: names of the form operations are not standardized, not all use add/edit, taxonomy terms afaik only use default. If you want to know if it is a new or existing entity, you can get that information with getEntity()->isNew()

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, I don't change the answer, because Maouna has already the code in his answer, so we keep both alternatives, +1 from me.

Comment: ->isNew() is needed for comments as well

Answer (score 10):

If you want to check for being on 'add' form, it is also possible to check that the entity is new, i.e.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_state->getFormObject() instanceof EntityForm) {
    $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
      //your code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you should always check the form_id and not using `$form['#action']`.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    // your code
  }
}
```

I'm not sure of the node edit/add form ids, you can use `dpm($form_id)` if you [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module or just use `print_r($form_id)` to find the `form_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also tell by the $form_id which is already present in the hook_form_alter.

$form_ids for nodes usually look like this:

- node add = node_NODE_TYPE_form
- node edit = node_NODE_TYPE_edit_form

So just use conditional logic for what you need and this is faster then using other methods listed in this.